# Question on discrete random variables $X,Y\in\{-1,1\}$

Tags: probability

I'm struggling with this question and I've looked everywhere online for the steps I should take with no luck:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ each take on either the value $1$ or $-1$.
>   $$\begin{align}&p(1,1)=p[X=1, Y=1]
> \\&p(1,-1)=p[X=1, Y=-1]
> \\&p(-1,1)=p[X=-1, Y=1]
> \\&p(-1,-1)=p[X=-1, Y=-1]\end{align}$$
>   Suppose $E(X)=E(Y)=0$, show that
>   $$\begin{align}&a)\qquad p(1,1)=p(-1,-1)
> \\&b)\qquad p(1,-1)=p(-1,1)\end{align}$$

I started this myself, using the formula for $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ and setting it $0$ to show that both sides are equivalent, but I'm not confident that I have done enough to prove that these probabilities are equivalent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want help with your proof, you will need to provide some account of what you tried.  As written I have no reason to be "confident that [you] have done enough to prove" those equalities.

Comment: Hint: $E(X)=0$ implies that $p(1,1)+p(1,-1)=p[X=1]=0.5=p(-1,-1)+p(-1,1)$.  Can you successfully explain why?  You can learn something similar from the condition that $E(Y)=0$.  These can then be combined in convenient ways.

Comment: Rather than looking everywhere online, you could start by writing down the definition of $E(X)$... :)

Comment: Thanks anderstood, but like I said in my post, I did that and worked with it but was not satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb P(X=1)=p(1,1)+p(1,-1)$, $\mathbb P(X=-1)=p(-1,1)+p(-1,-1)$, so 
$$
\mathbb E[X]=1\cdot (p(1,1)+p(1,-1))+(-1)\cdot (p(-1,1)+p(-1,-1))=0
$$
We get 
$$
p(1,1)+p(1,-1) = p(-1,1)+p(-1,-1).
$$
Using $\mathbb E[Y]=0$, get 
$$
p(1,1)+p(-1,1) = p(1,-1)+p(-1,-1).
$$
Subtract second equality from the first one and get
$$
p(1,-1) - p(-1,1) = p(-1,1) -  p(1,-1)
$$
which immediately give $p(-1,1) =  p(1,-1)$.

Then change right and left hand sides of the first equality as 
$$
p(-1,1)+p(-1,-1)=p(1,1)+p(1,-1)
$$
and subtract the second equality again. You will get $p(1,1)=p(-1,-1)$.